# Cell reference with hyperlinked text

Tags: excel, hyperlink

I am attempting to do something which sounds very simple, yet I couldn't find an answer anywhere online or here.

I am building an Excel database and have the main sheet with all the data I need, in which everything works great. I have many cells with text, and that text contains a hyperlink (in which I mean the URL is different than the text in the cell).

I have many other sheets which reference the main one. I have attempted to simply link the cells to their counterparts in the main (using a simple =location formula), but that only copies the text.
I then tried using =HYPERLINK(location), but that copies the text and creates a hyperlink, using the text as a URL instead of importing the URL I originally used.

What I want to do is link to another cell, displaying the text, but giving it the original URL I used in the main sheet.

EDIT: I want to be clear, that I can't use =HYPERLINK(location, name) because that still references the text in the original cell, NOT its hyperlink.
It could work if there would be a way to link a cell to the hyperlink in another cell, not the text in that cell.

Is such a thing possible at all without starting to use MACRO commands?
Not that it's a deal breaker, but I'd rather not get into it if I don't have to (since other people will work on it in the future, and they might not know anything about it).

Answer (score 2):

A short **User Defined Function** (aka UDF) can strip the [.Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx) from the [Hyperlink object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174231(v=office.11).aspx).

```
Function what_url(rHL As Range)
    If CBool(rHL.Cells(1).Hyperlinks.Count) Then
        what_url = rHL.Hyperlinks(1).Address
    Else
        what_url = "not a hylerlink"
    End If
End Function
```

There is also a [.SubAddress property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa215722(v=office.11).aspx) that can be appended to the .Address if required.

Comment: @NimrodYanai at least give an upvote and mark this accepted since it seems to have [pointed you in the right direction](http://superuser.com/questions/998139/geturl-excel-vba-function)

Comment: Hi sorry.
I've voted up but even if it pointed me in a direction that might lead to the answer, it didn't solve my problem.
I have attempted several variations of this solution, but so far with varied degrees of success, and never a complete solution.

Still looking for the answer you guys! :)